# OpenCv as static library using cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a cmake that generate NSVC project for a project and it includes opencv in the shared format (using *.dll)

I want to change the cmake so it can link the opencv static libraries.

My cmake in simple form is as follow:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${LIBLAS_LIBRARIES}
    optimized ${LIBE57_LIBRARIES}
    debug ${LIBE57_LIBRARIES_DEBUG}
    optimized ${CERES_LIBRARIES}
    debug ${CERES_LIBRARIES_DEBUG})
```

I call this cmake as follow:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64"  path/to/target/project
```

based on some questions that I found here is so, I tried these, and none of them work:

1. I add this to the start of cmake:

   set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES,FALSE)
2. I called cmake as follow:

   cmake -G -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF "Visual Studio 11 Win64" path/to/project

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64"   // don't seperate them

Comment: Thanks . That worked, but how can I set it inside cmake?